# How can I query collection with EF Core using custom equality check?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have two joined tables:

User > Device

A user can have many devices joined on FK user_ID. The device table has a primary key ID. But the device also has a token which is considered unique.

I am trying to select users that don't have a token:

```cs
IQueryable<User> users = DbContext.Users.Where(u => u.ID == _id && !u.Devices.Contains(device));
```

the `device` passed in here has a token and the `Device` model has an `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides that test for equality only on the token:

```cs
public bool Equals(Device comp)
{
  return comp.DeviceId.Equals(this.DeviceId);
}
```

So if I select users first then in code query the Device collection I can check the user doesn't already have the device associated:

```cs
IQueryable<User> users = DbContext.Users.Where(u => u.ID == _id);

User user = users.First();

if (!user.Devices.Contains(device))
{
  ...Contains here has compared devices based only on device token        
}
```

But EF Core constructs the query:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) [u].[ID], ...{other user properties cut for brevity}
      FROM [Users] AS [u]
      WHERE ([u].[ID] = @__id_0) AND @__8__locals1_device_1_Id NOT IN (
          SELECT [d].[Id]
          FROM [Device] AS [d]
          WHERE [u].[ID] = [d].[User_ID]
      )
```

This looks to me like I can only test for equality based on the ID property of the Device...

Is there any way of constructing an EF Core query that would match the code Equality/GetHashCode checks or do I have to do this in code?

Comment: You may want to post the devices model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your case. Please find the code below. And see comments for explanations.

```
// user class
public partial class tempu
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<tempd> tempds { get; set; }
}

// device class
public partial class tempd
{
    public int? token { get; set; }
    public int? uid { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public tempu tempus { get; set; }
}

// context
modelBuilder.Entity<tempu>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("tempu");
});

//// this is do the mapping of one to many
modelBuilder.Entity<tempd>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("tempd")
    .HasOne(p => p.tempus)
    .WithMany(i => i.tempds)
    .HasForeignKey(b => b.uid);
});

// linq query
var results = _context.tempu
      .Where(t => t.tempds.Any(y => y.token == null)) //// this will check if device id can be null in any case, 
      .Include(s => s.tempds) //// this will do the join
      .ToList();

// generated sql
SELECT [t].[id], [t].[name]
FROM [tempu] AS [t]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [tempd] AS [y]
    WHERE [y].[token] IS NULL AND ([t].[id] = [y].[uid]))
ORDER BY [t].[id]
```